# Is our death decided before our birth?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, death, qadar

Nothing happens without Almighty's wish.If a person wish death for other person or his own will the person die? or he will die when his time arrives? Can a person die before his time arrives? Can a person delay his death? Please answer....

Comment: can a person die before his time arrives etc. is answered here:  https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46753/is-death-time-predestined-or-can-it-be-extended-by-supplication

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is death time predestined or can it be extended by supplication?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46753/is-death-time-predestined-or-can-it-be-extended-by-supplication)

Answer (score 0):

According to Ahadith, the fate of people is written every year at the night of Qadr, until the next year, that is one is about to die, when and how it will happen, and its based on his/her actions and deeds.

God loves some of his people, therefore hasten their death in order not to fall into sins

A Sahih Hadith says that the number of dead people due to sins are more than those who died by their natural death, and also the number of those who got longer life time is more than ...

[i dont remember the full hadith, but i can bring it if you want]

So yes is decided but based on ourselves, and it doesnt mean the we have no choice to change our fate